# Error creation new table in Room database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I´m creating a new table in Room but I have a error with the migration. The problem is in favoriteId, there is a different between what is expected (primaryKeyPosition=1) and what is found in (primaryKeyPosition=0). If I delete data, it works fine.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle: favoriteRetailer(com.tiendeo.core.data.model.local.favorite.FavoriteRetailerLocalEntity).
>    Expected:
>   TableInfo{name='favoriteRetailer', columns={lon=Column{name='lon', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, retailerId=Column{name='retailerId', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, countryCode=Column{name='countryCode', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, favoriteId=Column{name='favoriteId', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, city=Column{name='city', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, retailerName=Column{name='retailerName', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, type=Column{name='type', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, lat=Column{name='lat', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
>    Found:
>   TableInfo{name='favoriteRetailer', columns={lon=Column{name='lon', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, retailerId=Column{name='retailerId', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, countryCode=Column{name='countryCode', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, favoriteId=Column{name='favoriteId', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, city=Column{name='city', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, retailerName=Column{name='retailerName', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, type=Column{name='type', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, lat=Column{name='lat', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}

This is my model and the migration

```
@Entity(tableName = "favoriteRetailer")
class FavoriteRetailerLocalEntity(
    @PrimaryKey var favoriteId: String,
    var city: String?,
    var lat: Float,
    var lon: Float,
    var retailerName: String,
    var retailerId: String,
    var countryCode: String,
    var type: Int
```

```
val TIENDEO_DB_MIGRATION_4_5: Migration = object : Migration(4, 5) {
  override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
    try{
      database.execSQL(
          "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'favoriteRetailer' ('favoriteId' TEXT NOT NULL, 'city' TEXT,  'lat' REAL NOT NULL, 'lon' REAL NOT NULL, 'retailerName' TEXT NOT NULL, 'retailerId' TEXT NOT NULL, 'countryCode' TEXT NOT NULL, 'type' INTEGER NOT NULL)"
      )
    } catch (e: java.lang.RuntimeException) {
      Log.i("Error", "error: $e. Problem with migration 4_5")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It was resolved. The problem was with the migration. I had to add `PRIMARY KEY('favoriteId')`

Comment: As you found the solution, its good practice if you post your answer and close the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your model class.

```
    @Entity(tableName = "favoriteRetailer")
class FavoriteRetailerLocalEntity(
    @PrimaryKey var favoriteId: String,
    var city: String?,
    var lat: Float,
    var lon: Float,
    var retailerName: String,
    var retailerId: String,
    var countryCode: String,
    var type: Int
```

the city is nullable but Room expected it to be not null.so change it like this

```
 @Entity(tableName = "favoriteRetailer")
    class FavoriteRetailerLocalEntity(
        @PrimaryKey var favoriteId: String,
        var city: String,
        var lat: Float,
        var lon: Float,
        var retailerName: String,
        var retailerId: String,
        var countryCode: String,
        var type: Int
```

Comment: That is not the problem. room doesn´t expect not null in city

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The problem was in the definition of table. I had to put
`PRIMARY KEY('id')`
in the of create table